# Still gets the error <open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)>

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I have read many posts that can help me to cope with the this issue.

this is the solution of this kind of error. (just insert a line of code to androidmanifest.xml)

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage=”true”
```

But in my case, that insertion does not work.
I am now developing a mobile app with react native.
The trouble is occured when I try to put the file on firebase storage.
Of course, I inserted that line of code to my androidmanifest.xml file.

```
<application
  android:name=”.MainApplication”
  android:label=”@string/app_name”
  android:icon=”@mipmap/ic_launcher”
  android:roundIcon=”@mipmap/ic_launcher_round”
  android:allowBackup=”false”
  android:theme=”@style/AppTheme”
  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage=”true”
>
```

And this is the bulidscript

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = “29.0.3”
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    targetSdkVersion = 29
    ndkVersion = “20.1.5948944”
    playServicesVersion = “17.0.0”
    androidMapsUtilsVersion = “2.2.3”
}
 …
}
```

And this is the uploading script

```
// uploads file
const pngRef = storage().ref(avatar/upload.png);
console.log(“pngRef”, pngRef);
await pngRef.putFile(fileUri);
const url = await storage()
  .ref(avatar/upload.png)
  .getDownloadURL();
console.log(“url”, url);
```

But still occurs the error.

```
open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

And I got the alert on my firebase console.

```
Your project's Cloud Firestore database '(default)' has insecure rules
```

Of course, I have allowed read and write for my developement.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

ADD: This is the firestore rule. The weird thing is this projects have been
working well, but suddenly appeared the error.

```
rules_version = '2';
  service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if true;
      }
    }
   }
```

Is there any solution with this? Is this the firebase error?
I will be happy if anyone helps me.

Comment: This message is about Cloud Firestore, a document database: "Your project's Cloud Firestore database '(default)' has insecure rules". The code and rules that you have in your code are related to Cloud Storage, which stores files. While both are part of Google Cloud and Firebase, they are otherwise not related to each other and that message has nothing to do with your Storage rules.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen. Thanks for reaching out to me, I added the firestore rule too.

Comment: As I explained, there are two completely different products involved here. What specifically doesn't work for you now?

Comment: Actually, there are many crud operations in my project. the error occurs in the part that involves the writing on the storage. After adding the photo of a document, the photo should be stored in firebase storage. But occurs error. Everything was fine in the past.
If you don't mind, Could you please teach me via anydesk or teamviewer?

Comment: No, that's not how Stack Overflow works. Also: you really should isolate the problem into a [minimal reproduction](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please). If there'a problem with file storage, you should be able to reproduce that without anything related to Firestore.

Comment: Sorry for the teamviewer, I am now confused....

Comment: So. @FrankvanPuffelen, should I edit the rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't really seen `rules_version` line in Firebase Storage but these default rules work in rules playground so there must be something wrong on client side.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Can you try wrapping your code in a try-catch? That might help getting some additional debugging details such as path you are trying to access.

```
try {
  const pngRef = storage().ref("avatar/upload.png");
  console.log(“pngRef”, pngRef);
  await pngRef.putFile(fileUri);
  const url = await storage()
    .ref("avatar/upload.png")
    .getDownloadURL();
console.log(“url”, url);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
  // This should contain additional details
}
```

Also please try adding the ref path in quotes as I've done above. Additionally, (likely not the issue) but make sure the code is in an async function. If it's still not fixed, please add the additional details from console in your question.

Comment: Thanks, @Dharmaraj. I followed your step. And I found the error. you were right. the error is from the client-side, in some cases, the input value can take the null. Really thanks.
I only regarded the error as the one from the rule. But the error was from another part. Thanks for teaching me. Have a Good day.

Comment: Dear everyone, please try to pay attention to the ref path... you need to have patience to get the error.